# Machine Learning in Python - Get the best possible feature-combination for a label

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk

My Question is as follows:

I know a little bit about ML in Python (using NLTK), and it works ok so far. I can get predictions given certain features. But I want to know, is there a way, to display the best features to achieve a label? I mean the direct opposite of what I've been doing so far (put in all circumstances, and get a label for that)

I try to make my question clear via an example:

Let's say I have a database with Soccer games.
The Labels are e.g.  'Win', 'Loss', 'Draw'.
The Features are e.g. 'Windspeed', 'Rain or not', 'Daytime', 'Fouls committed' etc.

Now I want to know: Under which circumstances will a Team achieve a Win, Loss or Draw? Basically I want to get back something like this:
Best conditions for Win: Windspeed=0, No Rain, Afternoon, Fouls=0 etc
Best conditions for Loss: ...

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to return the actual best conditions, or you want to be able to give conditions and it will predict win draw or loss?

Comment: The actual best conditions.

Comment: have you looked into logistic regression? It tells you the probability so whatever the conditions with the probability closest to 1 would have the best conditions theoretically

Comment: No, but I'll start looking now. I thought there might be an "easy way" from a trained classifier to get the desired output.

Comment: well that's what you would do with logistic regression. You train it and then have it output the optimal option. I've never used it for that, but I'm sure you could! Look at scikit learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>My paint skills aren't the best!</sub>
All I know is theory, so well you'll have to look for the code..

If you have only 1 case(The best for "x" situations) the diagram becomes something like (It won't be 2-D, but something like this):
[image: The 3 dots]
Green (Win), Orange(Draw), Red(Lose)

Now if you want to predict whether the team wins, loses or draws, you have (at least) 2 models to classify:

1. [Linear Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression), the separator is the Perpendicular bisector of the line joining the 2 points:

   [image: Linear Regression]
2. [K-nearest-neighbours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm): it is done just by calculating the distance from all the points, and classifying the point as the same as the closest..
   [image: Something!!!]

So, for example, if you have a new data, and have to classify it, here's how:

1. We have a new point, with certain attributes..
   [image: New Point]
2. We classify it by seeing/calculating which side of the line the point comes in (or seeing how far it is from our benchmark situations...
   [image: Classified Point]

> Note: You will have to give some weightage to each factor, for more accuracy..

Answer (score 0):

You could compute the representativeness of each feature to separate the classes via feature weighting. The most common method for feature selection (and therefore feature weighting) in Text Classification is chi^2. This measure will tell you which features are better. Based on this information you can analyse the specific values that are best for every case. I hope this helps.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have to do this in python, but if not, I would suggest Weka.  If you're unfamiliar with it, here's a link to a set of tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gd5HwYYOz2U

Basically, you'd just need to write a program to extract your features and labels and then output a .arff file. Once you've generated a .arff file, you can feed this to Weka and run myriad different classifiers on it to figure out what model best fits your data. If necessary, you can then program this model to operate on your data.  Weka has plenty of ways to analyze your results and to graphically display said results.  It's truly amazing.